# why I got error The entity type LAB_INVOICE_VIEW is not part of the model for the current context.?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am using VS2015 and tried to add new table to my entity data model but when I saved it its deleted all data under file context.cs file and showed errors all models used before deleted from entity model,

So I tried to manually add the Model to my DBcontext I found the steps in this link :

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426289/manually-create-model-for-single-table-in-entity-framework
```

I did the following steps :

1- created the database view LAB_INVOICE_VIEW

2- created the model

3- added manually the model to my DBcontext :

```
public virtual DbSet<LAB_INVOICE_VIEW> LAB_INVOICE_VIEW { get; set; }
```

4- added the configuration also to the model under the model columns :

```
class MyTableConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<LAB_INVOICE_VIEW>
    {
        public MyTableConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("dbo.LAB_INVOICE_VIEW");
        }
    }
```

5- added the override code to Dbcontext.cs :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyTableConfiguration());
        }
```

6- I changed the connection string from EF string to ADO.NET string but I got the errors :

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:



AljawdahNewSite.Models.Customers: : EntityType 'Customers' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

AljawdahNewSite.Models.Departments: : EntityType 'Departments' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

AljawdahNewSite.Models.Customers_Price_List: : EntityType 'Customers_Price_List' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

AljawdahNewSite.Models.LabTests: : EntityType 'LabTests' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

AljawdahNewSite.Models.Groups: : EntityType 'Groups' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

AljawdahNewSite.Models.Lab_Sample_status: : EntityType 'Lab_Sample_status' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

AljawdahNewSite.Models.Patients: : EntityType 'Patients' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

7- I tried the solutions in the link but still got the error :

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688922/the-entity-type-type-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context
```

please I need your help .

Comment: From your description it's not really clear what happened and how you continued. Are you still using the EDMX? Because if you do, `OnModelCreating` won't run.

Comment: @GertArnold  yes I'm using EDMX with previous used tables and models without any errors but only this last model I cannot add it to the diagram so I tried to add it manually to the context

Comment: But then I don't understand step 6 and 7. The EDMX requires an entity connection string. And how did you fix the other errors? It looks like you're having some messy mixture of database-first and code-first code.

Comment: @GertArnold no.6 one solution said change EF connection string to ADO.NET and it will work I changed it but I got another errors related to the models already added to EDMX , No 7 the site with some solutions how to solve this issue I tried it but still got the error , can I add more than one connection string and use it with the last model with ADO.NET way ?

Comment: I can't see your code, but to mee it seems you have to delete the EDMX completely. You can't use it in combination with other mapping configuration in `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: @GertArnold How to delete the EDMX completely because also I deleted it and after I added again all tables again some tables added with different names for example Patients table added as Patient without s and I have another errors and I have to update the whole project again ?

Comment: At this point nobody knows what you've been doing, but one thing is clear, it turned into a complete mess. I'd say, start from scratch in a new project, or revert your changes from source control and try again.

Comment: @GertArnold Actually I have copy of my project I used old copy and everything fine just this point now how to add last table to .EDMX manually , what the code you need to see I will send it ?  thank you for your help

Comment: @GertArnold hello sir I changed the way and created another connection string and used ADO.NET but I faced one issue I need your help please see this issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70319023/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the EDMX file and created new EF again and added all models , This solved my issue .

Thank you Mr Gert